# Rest POST an XML with multipart/form-data

Tags: groovy

How to do a Rest POST an XML with multipart/form-data
e.g.

```
restClient.post(
            uri: "/tempDirectory",
            requestContentType: 'multipart/form-data',
            headers: ["X-Auth-Token": accessToken],
            body : [ file : tempFile ]
    )
```

Seems failure is coming from body field

Comment: What is the exact error / issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was solved by using MultipartEntityBuilder for building multipart post request as prior I was encountering "no encoder found" error